# A line with a parametric vector equation

Tags: matrices, vectors

I am struggling with this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Please do not apply the algebraic-geometry tag to elementary problems involving algebra and geometry, as per the tag description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how a parametric equation works?

**Hint**

What does the value of (the parameter) $t$ have to be for the first coordinate to be $-8$?

Once you have this value of $t$, what is the value of the second coordinate?

Comment: I believe $t$ has to be -2?

Comment: Correct, and then you know all the other coordinates as well.

Comment: Therefore the answer is $19$?

Comment: Yes, that's right :-).

Answer (score 1):

If $x_1=-8$, then we  have $t=-2$.

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: so  $x2=9+-2*-5=19$?

Comment: Yes, we have $x_2=19.$